# Javascript - Pulling specific objects out of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

New to coding & learning javascript & node.js. I have an array of 50 image results here: http://mistakes.io/#6204f3edd56b8891075d

I am trying to pull out two specific objects in that array: "MediaUrl" and "SourceUrl".

I can pull out an individual result via `body.d.results[15].MediaUrl` for example, but how do I pull out all 50 MediaUrl or SourceUrl? I was thinking that I could achieve this with a for of for-in loop but unclear how to do so. The goal is to pull those objects out and then be able to pick randomly from those specific elements. Would I first have to create a variable with an array like `var myArray = ["body.d.results[0].MediaUrl", body.d.results[1].MediaUrl", body.d.results[3].MediaUrl", ...]` ?

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have been searching up and down for examples and tutorials but not sure how to phrase what I am looking for. I believe this question is different than here: [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array) because it doesn't explain how to pick randomly as well.

Comment: Since you have them in a perfectly functional array, why not simply randomly pick like this: `body.d.results[Math.floor(Math.random() * body.d.results.length)].MediaUrl`? Taking them out and separating them into a different array seems needless here.

Comment: Also, duplicate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store them all in their own array, you can easily just walk through the array and assign the result to a new array:

```
var mediaUrlResult = [];
var sourceUrlResult = [];
for(var i = 0; i < body.d.result.length; i++){
    mediaUrlResult.push(body.d.result.MediaUrl);
    sourceUrlResult.push(body.d.result.SourceUrl);
}
```

This will give you two arrays with the values in them. Now, as for random picking, you could do the following:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * Array.length)
```

The above will give you an integer number between 0 and the arrays length (excluding the arrays length itself thanks to `Math.floor` (this is useful because there isn't actually an item at the array's length index, which could spell trouble otherwise!)) Now you could pull this random value out of your array:

```
sourceUrlResult[Math.floor(Math.random() * sourceUrlResult.length)];
```

But easier than this is to simply pack all your *results* into a single variable, and then start from there - since it is already in memory there is no need to duplicate data you have already!

```
var array = body.d.results;
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
console.log('src:', array[randomIndex].SourceUrl, 'media:', array[randomIndex].Media)
```

Comment: Really appreciate you sharing all of these options here! Seems most in line with what I am trying to achieve.  In fact everyone's answers & suggestions are absolutely helpful especially from the standpoint of learning. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To pull out an array of `MediaUrl`s, run it through a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) call:

```
var mediaUrls = arr.map(function (x) {
    return x["MediaUrl"];
});
```

Since `map` "creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array", returned is this array:

```
["http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-rshrTkUD4Do/TV6mxlXoUxI/AAAAAAAAACw/6kb0msv26iA/s1600/Tina+Modotti.jpg", "http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/736x/ee/cf/5f/eecf5f6d5e776104548f542bd269f631.jpg", ...]
```

Snippet (using a shortened version of your JSON):

```js
var d = [{
  "__metadata": {
    "uri": "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/Image?Query='Photography by tina modotti'&ImageFilters='Size:Large'&$skip=0&$top=1",
    "type": "ImageResult"
  },
  "ID": "acedb185-cc7e-4da8-89be-bd107f4a6528",
  "Title": "tina modotti biography from profots com tina modotti was a remarkable ...",
  "MediaUrl": "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-rshrTkUD4Do/TV6mxlXoUxI/AAAAAAAAACw/6kb0msv26iA/s1600/Tina+Modotti.jpg",
  "SourceUrl": "http://mastersofphotography.blogspot.com.au/2011/02/tina-modotti.html",
  "DisplayUrl": "mastersofphotography.blogspot.com.au/2011/02/tina-modotti.html",
  "Width": "530",
  "Height": "480",
  "FileSize": "87133",
  "ContentType": "image/jpeg",
  "Thumbnail": {
    "__metadata": {
      "type": "Bing.Thumbnail"
    },
    "MediaUrl": "http://ts2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.M1dd1aa7a5fc5f4b73e1258d402d0f5dbH0&pid=15.1",
    "ContentType": "image/jpg",
    "Width": "480",
    "Height": "434",
    "FileSize": "27551"
  }
}, {
  "__metadata": {
    "uri": "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/Image?Query='Photography by tina modotti'&ImageFilters='Size:Large'&$skip=1&$top=1",
    "type": "ImageResult"
  },
  "ID": "5acade4e-106e-49af-b7b4-c3e89fdd2f6d",
  "Title": "Tina Modotti | Indigenous | Pinterest",
  "MediaUrl": "http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/736x/ee/cf/5f/eecf5f6d5e776104548f542bd269f631.jpg",
  "SourceUrl": "http://pinterest.com/pin/393994667370497691/",
  "DisplayUrl": "pinterest.com/pin/393994667370497691",
  "Width": "654",
  "Height": "720",
  "FileSize": "168465",
  "ContentType": "image/jpeg",
  "Thumbnail": {
    "__metadata": {
      "type": "Bing.Thumbnail"
    },
    "MediaUrl": "http://ts4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.M94668199c6351c86fc3d8a8267c19602o2&pid=15.1",
    "ContentType": "image/jpg",
    "Width": "272",
    "Height": "300",
    "FileSize": "11661"
  }
}, {
  "__metadata": {
    "uri": "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/Image?Query='Photography by tina modotti'&ImageFilters='Size:Large'&$skip=2&$top=1",
    "type": "ImageResult"
  },
  "ID": "aa661abe-dedc-47c4-a524-fa83e1efbdb2",
  "Title": "Tina Modotti",
  "MediaUrl": "http://www.masters-of-photography.com/images/full/modotti/modotti_roses.jpg",
  "SourceUrl": "http://www.masters-of-photography.com/M/modotti/modotti_roses_full.html",
  "DisplayUrl": "www.masters-of-photography.com/M/modotti/modotti_roses_full.html",
  "Width": "610",
  "Height": "480",
  "FileSize": "78365",
  "ContentType": "image/jpeg",
  "Thumbnail": {
    "__metadata": {
      "type": "Bing.Thumbnail"
    },
    "MediaUrl": "http://ts1.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.Maeca6f4759d245091ae2276829dca4efo0&pid=15.1",
    "ContentType": "image/jpg",
    "Width": "300",
    "Height": "236",
    "FileSize": "8950"
  }
}];

console.log(d.map(function(x) {
  return x["MediaUrl"];
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way i would do it.

```
var newArray = body.d.results.map(function(obj){
   return {MediaUrl: obj['MediaUrl'], SourceUrl: obj['SourceUrl']}
});
function getFromRandomArray(array) {
   return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * Array.length)]
}
```

and whenever you want a random value `getFromArray(newArray)`

Comment: I wouldn't use `getFromArray`, but rather something like `getRandomFromArray`. It's a nitpick but something I've been paying more attention to lately.

Comment: Totally makes sense. Either i should provide shuffled array or i should rename it. Thanks for the feedback.